# <%@taglib uri="www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %> <form:errors path="student1.*" /> causing "Unable to compile JSP page" error

Tags: forms, jsp, spring-mvc, error-handling, taglib

I am trying to learn Spring MVC and when tried out a sample from internet, i am getting the following error:

---

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:600)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:363)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:168)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1244)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.tomcat.util.descriptor.tld.TldResourcePath.hashCode(TldResourcePath.java:164)
    java.util.HashMap.hash(HashMap.java:338)
    java.util.HashMap.get(HashMap.java:556)
```

---

This is my JSP page:

```
<%@taglib uri="www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Admission Form</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>${header_msg}</h1>
<h3>Admission Form for Engineering Courses</h3>

<form:errors path="student1.*" />
<form action="/Admissions/submitAdmissionForm.html" method="post">
    <table>
    <tr><td> Student's Name :   </td><td>   <input type="text" name="studentName" />    </td></tr>
    <tr><td> Student's Hobby :  </td><td>   <input type="text" name="studentHobby" />   </td></tr>
    <tr><td> Date of Birth :    </td><td>   <input type="text" name="studentDOB" />     </td></tr>
    <tr><td> Mobile No :        </td><td>   <input type="text" name="studentMobile" />  </td></tr>

    <tr><td> Skill set :        </td><td>   <select name="studentSkills" multiple>
                                            <option value="Core Java">Core Java</option>
                                            <option value="Spring Core">Spring Core</option>
                                            <option value="Spring MVC">Spring MVC</option>
                                            </select> </td></tr>
    </table>

    <table>
    <tr><td> Address :  </td></tr>
    <tr><td> Country:   <input type="text" name="studentAddress.country" />     </td>
        <td> City:      <input type="text" name="studentAddress.city" />        </td>
        <td> Street:    <input type="text" name="studentAddress.street" />      </td>
        <td> Pin code:  <input type="text" name="studentAddress.pincode" />     </td></tr>

    <tr><td> </td><td>  <input type="submit" value="Submit this form" />        </td></tr>
    </table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

My controller class contains the below code:

```
@ModelAttribute
public void addingCommonObjects(ModelAndView model) {

    model.addObject("header_msg", "College of Engineering, Adoor");
}

@RequestMapping(value="/submitAdmissionForm.html", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView submitAdmissionForm(@ModelAttribute("student1") Student student, BindingResult result) {

    if(result.hasErrors()) {
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("AdmissionForm");
        return model;
    }
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("AdmissionFormSuccess");
    return model;
}
```

Before adding `BindingResult` in controller and `<form:errors>` in the JSP page everything was working fine.
This might be a small issue in code when you guys look, but i've been trying to identify the issue for the last 3-4 days.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%@taglib uri="www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
```

uri is incorrect in the above line.**http** is missing in the uri. try below

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
```

Comment: Wow! thanks a lot. i spent a lot of time over this http :-/